# jQuery not working in AJAX Loaded page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, click

I am using jQuery to load a page by AJAX using $.ajax (suppose test.html).
Its a simple HTML document with a few buttons and associated animations upon clicking them (also using jQuery).
The .click() properties associated are working fine when I load the page directly but the buttons fail to respond when I click them in the AJAX loaded version.
Since I am too tires to actually explain all the glum that I am doing, I am simply writing all the code below, apologies for this. Here are the required codes in the files.

```
<!-- p11.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="c/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="c/js/jtry11.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='c/css/css11.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go1">Load Something Using AJAX</button>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <div id="showButton">
      <button id="showLoadedPage">Show the Page</button>
  </div>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the next

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#results').hide();
    $('#msg').hide();
    $('#showButton').hide();
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#loaded').hide();

    $('#load').live('click', function()
    {
        $('#load').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#msg').show('fast');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                    $('#results').append(html);
            }
        });
        $('#msg').ajaxSuccess(function(evt, request, settings){
           $(this).append('Click the Button Below to View the Page');
           $('#showButton').show('slow');
           $('#hideLoadedPage').hide();
           $('#loading').hide();
           $('#loaded').show();
        });
    });

    $('#showLoadedPage').live('click', function() {
        $('#loaded').hide('slow');
        $('#msg').hide('slow');
        $('#results').show('fast');
        $('.shower').hide();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#hideLoadedPage').show();
    });

    $('#hideLoadedPage').live('click', function() {
        $('#results').hide('fast');
        $('.shower').hide();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#showLoadedPage').show();
    });

    $('.hider').live('click', function() {
        $('.shower').show();
        $(this).hide();
        $('p.one').hide('slow');
        $('p.two').hide('medium');
        $('p.three').hide('fast');
    });

    $('.shower').live('click', function() {
        $('.hider').show();
        $(this).hide();
        $('p.one').show('slow');
        $('p.two').show('medium');
        $('p.three').show('fast');
    });

    $('p.*').live('click', function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        if( $('p').is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.shower').show();
        }
        if( $('p.*').is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.hider').show();
        }
    });
});
```

and the last

```
<!-- test.html -->
Page Loaded by Ajax.
Not the original Page

<center>
    <button class="hider">
        <img src="c/images/zoom_out.png" alt="zoom_out" />
        Hide 'em
    </button>
    <button class="shower">
        <img src="c/images/zoom_in.png" alt="zoom_out" />
        Show it
    </button>
    <p class="one">Hiya</p>
    <p class="two">Such interesting text, eh?</p>
    <p class="three">The third Paragraph</p>
</center>
```

I hope I am not making some big time mistake?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sounds like you need

```
$('#go1').live('click', function() {});
```

$.fn.live, as event handlers are only registered on initial dom creation, and you're repopulating the DOM and those aren't attached.

More info @ http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: Can you update the description with your updated code, or paste a live link? And you did remember to replace *all* .click event handler assignments which need to be reapplied with $('selector').live('click', function(){} ); ?

Comment: Yes it Works now! Thanks! In the first time I had replaced it only in the go button, but now i did it for all. What exactly is the difference between .click and .live()? does this mean that I can use .live always in place of click?

Comment: Live event handlers I believe are bound to the document itself instead of specific elements, and so when the event object is passed after an event occurrence like a 'click' it detects which element was clicked, and smartly invokes the right event handlers for their respective events/elements. 

You should only use it when you're repopulating the DOM with elements such as in this case, you shouldn't always need it.

Comment: Please check this question too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420774/selecting-elements-in-jquery

Comment: better to use .delegate() is more or less the same as .live() , but is more robust and i have found works better than .live() accross browsers
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High - `.delegate` wasn't in the stable version of jQuery when I posted this answer.

Comment: Just a note - .live() is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and replaced by .on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading that right you are adding the click handlers at the beginning. These only affect current buttons. You may just need to change that to a Live event.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#peopleResult_list").on('click','a', function(event){
    //do you code here  
 });
```

on event work for current dom in your page and any dom loaded by ajax in the future