# Selecting elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

In continuation of the [question at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419433/jquery-not-working-in-ajax-loaded-page) I wanted to add some functionality in test.html
The event trigger is 'clicking' on any <p class=""> tag.
After clicking I wanted that particular <p> to disappear (which was fairly straightforward) **but** I also want that

1. If out of the three either one or two <p> are hidden, then "Hide 'em" button should 'show' along with "Show 'em" **But**
2. If all <p> are hidden then "Hide 'em" should also get Hidden **And**
3. When all <p> are visible then "Show 'em" should get Hidden.

I tried to go about the thing with my knowledge of jQuery selectors and the selector documentation avaliable, but didn't reach anywhere near what I want. This is what I have done till now.

```
$('p.*').live('click', function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        if( $('p').is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.shower').show();
        }
        if( $('p.*').is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.hider').show();
        }

    });
```

However This code does not selectively toggle at the extreme conditions of all <p> hidden

Comment: I added what i have done till now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it

```
var all_ps = $('p.*').length;
var hidden_ps = 0;

$('p.*').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide('slow');
    hidden_ps++;
    updateButtons();
});
function updateButtons()
{
    $('.hider').show();
    $('.shower').show();
    if(hidden_ps == all_ps-1) {
        $('.hider').hide();
    } else if(hidden_ps == 0) {
        $('.shower').hide();
    }
}
function resetButtons()
{
    $('p.*').show();
    hidden_ps = 0;
    updateButtons()
}
```

Comment: where is resetButtons() getting used?

Comment: You'd call that from the "Show 'em" button. $('.shower').click(resetButtons)

Comment: somehow not working. I'll check it out again in a little while and reply more about it again in a little while... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It works! I actually didn't realise that I could integrate standard Javascript into jQuery so naturally since I have just started with jQuery!