# ajax load disables other links, form submitted even if return false ,

Tags: python, django, jquery

I'm trying to load portions of a form based on validation results. here is the code I'm using
its the same for all those button on the form.

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      noPgLoad(this);
});
function noPgLoad(button){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data : serialized_data,
    success: function(data,textStatus,xhr){
           $('#somediv').replaceWith(data);
           return false;
           },
    error: fail,
    dataType: "html"
 });
}
```

In django views i check if request.is_ajax()
ISSUES :

1. ajax call replaces right validation results,but other links on the page doesn't function.
2. when clicked on the button after successful ajax call it submits the form.i.e, the jquery function for ajax is not called and so form is submitted.
   My whole day has gone with this,being Ajax newbie.Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your first problem, but I think you can solve the second by using `live` ([see jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) instead of `click`

```
$("#button").live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  noPgLoad(this);
});
```

To explain briefly, when you use `click`, it only applies to the elements on the page. I think that your code `$('somediv').replaceWith(data)` is replacing the button. Clicks on the new button will not trigger the handler because it was added after the handler was attached.

When you use `live` then add a new button, then clicks on the new button will trigger the handler.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair! I did find this but couldn't answer as I dont have adequate score to answer my own question within 8hrs.....appreciate it :)...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419433/jquery-not-working-in-ajax-loaded-page